# How to make jQuery File Upload(jQuery UI version) work on file inputs dynamically created

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-file-upload

I need to use this [plugin](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/jquery-ui.html) to upload excel files.
I use the jQuery UI version because lets me configure the number of files that are allowed to be uploaded, the allowed file types and also my whole site uses jQuery UI.
Well,using [this example](https://github.com/i-e-b/jQueryFileUpload.Net) provided in the plugin page I had **almost** everything I need.
Everything works smoothly when the file input is put in the raw code of the site. However, when I try to use the same code

```
<div id="fileupload">
    <form action="FileTransferHandler.ashx" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="fileupload-buttonbar">
            <label class="fileinput-button">
                <span>Cargar Excel...</span>
                <input type="file" name="files" multiple="multiple" />
            </label>           
            <div class="fileupload-progressbar"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="fileupload-content">
        <table class="files"></table>
    </div>
</div>
```

to create some file inputs dynamically, not only it does nothing , but the input files don't even get styled.

Is there any way to explicitly tell a input file to use this plugin, something similar to what is use with the [basic version](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/basic.html)

As always any advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to reinitialize plugin on new added elements if plugin doesn't accept any kind of delegation

Comment: I tried [this](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/API)  `$('#fieldName').fileupload();` Once all the file inputs were created, but still cant get any results :(